# Differentiate between defaults, web-configurable, and fixed app_settings in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am setting up an Azure web app. I want some values to be added to `app_settings` only if they are not already present (so they can be overridden manually in the portal) and others I want to force to a fixed value.

I've worked out a way of doing this, but I have to pass a `merge_with_existing` variable which I set to `n` when the environment is being created for the first time (otherwise the `data.azurerm_linux_web_app.app` will throw an exception because the app doesn't already exist).

Is there a way of doing this without requiring a variable?

```
locals {
  app_name = "${var.environment}myappname"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
data "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  count = var.merge_with_existing == "n" ? 0 : 1

  name = local.app_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}


locals {
  scopes = "api://${var.aad_tenant_id}/access_as_user"

  app_settings_template = {
    
    web_configurable_values = {
      APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING = ""
      Logging__LogLevel__Default = "Information"
      "Logging__LogLevel__Microsoft.AspNetCore" = "Information"
      WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS = "28"
    }

    priority_values = {
      AllowedHosts = "*"
      APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION = "1.0.0"
      APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION = "1.0.0"
      ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~2"
      DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~3"
      InstrumentationEngine_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~1"
      XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_BaseExtensions = "~"
      XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode = "recommended"
      XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_PreemptSdk = "disabled"
    }
  }

  app_settings = merge(
    var.merge_with_existing == "n" 
      ? local.app_settings_template.web_configurable_values
      : merge(
          local.app_settings_template.web_configurable_values,
          data.azurerm_linux_web_app.app[0].app_settings),
    local.app_settings_template.priority_values)
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "app_service_plan" {
  name                = "${var.environment}myappname"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                = "${var.environment}myappname"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.app_service_plan.id
  https_only          = true

  site_config {
    always_on = false
    application_stack {
        dotnet_version  = "7.0"
    }
  }


  app_settings = local.app_settings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you can try with [try - Functions  | HashiCorp Developer](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/try)

```
data "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name = local.app_name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_service_plan.app_service_plan,
  ]
}

locals {
  scopes = "api://${data.azuread_client_config.tenant_id}/access_as_user"

  app_settings_template = {
    
    web_configurable_values = {
      APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING = ""
      Logging__LogLevel__Default = "Information"
      "Logging__LogLevel__Microsoft.AspNetCore" = "Information"
      WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS = "28"
    }

    priority_values = {
      AllowedHosts = "*"
      APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION = "1.0.0"
      APPINSIGHTS_SNAPSHOTFEATURE_VERSION = "1.0.0"
      ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~2"
      DiagnosticServices_EXTENSION_VERSION = "~3"
      ....
    }
  }

  existing_app_settings = try(data.azurerm_linux_web_app.app.app_settings, {})

  app_settings = merge(
    local.app_settings_template.web_configurable_values,
    existing_app_settings,
    local.app_settings_template.priority_values,
  )
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "app_service_plan" {
  name                = "kavmyappname"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "B1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                = "kaamyappname"
 resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.app_service_plan.id
  https_only          = true

  site_config {
    always_on = false
    application_stack {
        dotnet_version  = "7.0"
    }
  }

  app_settings = local.app_settings
}
```

[image]

**Reference** :  [try - Functions - Configuration Language | Terraform | HashiCorp Developer](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/try)